# what is the easiest/best way to validate a form using js?

Tags: javascript, forms

**objective:**
i want a user to enter information on a form, then i will use that info to generate different results.

**heres my code:**
http://jsfiddle.net/5HUVm/

```
<form id="form1" name="form1" method="post">
    <table>
        <tr>
            <td>I am interested in:</td>
            <td><input type="radio" name="choice" value="consume" id="consume"/> Cosuming and/or distributing OTC Markets data
            </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td></td>
            <td><input type="radio" name="choice" value="extranet" id="extranet"/> Providing connectivity to OTC Markets(Extranet)</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>Data products:</td>
            <td><input type="checkbox" name="realtime" value="realtime" id="realTime">Real-time data</td>
            <td><input type="checkbox" name="otcdata" value="otcdata" id="compData">OTC Company Data</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td></td>
            <td><input type="checkbox" name="eodprice" value="eodprice" id="eod">End of Day Pricing Data</td>
            <td><input type="checkbox" name="otccompliance" value="otccompliance" id="otcComp">OTC Compliance Data</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td></td>
            <td><input type="checkbox" name="otcsecurity" value="otcsecurity" id="otcSec">OTC Security Data</td>            
            <td><input type="checkbox" name="otcqhistory" value="otchistory" id="otcHist">OTC Quote History</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>

            <td>Data use:</td>
            <td>
                <select name="products" id="prod">
                    <option value="select">Select</option>
                    <option value="personal">Personal Use Only</option>
                    <option value="distEx">Distribute Externally Only</option>
                    <option value="distIn">Distribute Internally Only</option>
                    <option value="distBoth">Distribute Externally &amp; Internally Only</option>
                </select>
            </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>Firm type:</td>
            <td>
                <select name="firm" id="firm">
                    <option value="select">Select</option>
                    <option value="broker">Broker-dealer</option>
                    <option value="oms">Order Management System</option>
                    <option value="finanInfo">Financial Information Service/Portal</option>
                    <option value="service">Service Bureau</option>
                    <option value="other">Other</option>
                </select>
            </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>
                <input type="reset" id="re">
                <input type="button" id="sub" value="Submit" onclick="valid(this)">
            </td>
        </tr>
    </table>
</form>
```

so as you can see there are checkboxes, radio buttons, drop downs.
what is the best way to validate what has been checked/selected?

**i was thinking:**
lots of if statements then use a variable to store a special "numbers" for the different choices made then taht number will be used to generate the result page

**for example:**
user chooses consuming, real time data, and end of day data that would be lets say choice 1
user clicks submit and the results page will show special links/articles.

Comment: yes! lots of if statement...Awesome idea! :)

Comment: `<table>` fail.  Tables are not layout. And seriously validation is a solved problem using HTML5 forms

Comment: @Brogrammer i detect sarcasm -.-!

Comment: @Raynos i see a few validation scripts that checks text input.. i use <table> cause it gets the job done for me in this one =/

Comment: @JoeChen [required](http://dev.w3.org/html5/spec-author-view/common-input-element-attributes.html#attr-input-required) and [pattern](http://dev.w3.org/html5/spec-author-view/common-input-element-attributes.html#attr-input-pattern) should do most of your validation for you

Comment: hmmm i think im asking the wrong question.. i just need to know what choices are checked that way i can create a special "number" for it then that number will be used sort of as a "seed?" to generate the results page..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are lots of validation scripts out there that will do exactly what your trying to do - don't reinvent the wheel .... go grab one and use it :

Prototype : http://tetlaw.id.au/view/blog/really-easy-field-validation-with-prototype

JQuery : http://bassistance.de/jquery-plugins/jquery-plugin-validation/

YUI : http://www.yuiblog.com/blog/2009/12/03/yui-3-gallery-form-module/

Answer (score 1):

The easiest way would be to use some form of plugin that has already been written but allows you to customise:

http://bassistance.de/jquery-plugins/jquery-plugin-validation/